# ¿Cómo puedo quitar los valores duplicados de ng-repeat en AngularJS (Angular 1)?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Como puedo listar los detalles del estudiante sin duplicidad.

Json:

```
  "data_students": [
    {
      "studen_id": 1,
      "studen_name": "Jenny",
      "studen_level": 5,
      "course_name": "Photoshop",
      "course_id": 2
    },
    {
      "studen_id": 1,
      "studen_name": "Jenny",
      "studen_level": 10,
      "course_name": "Photoshop",
      "course_id": 2
    },
    {
      "studen_id": 1,
      "studen_name": "Jenny",
      "studen_level": 15,
      "course_name": "Photoshop",
      "course_id": 2
    },
```

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data_students" ng-if="params.studen_level==item.studen_level">
<h2{{item.student_name}}></h2>
<h3>{{item.course_id}} | {{item.course_name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que no te esta sacando valores duplicados. Solo que tienes algunos errores sintácticos.

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in data_students" ng-if="params.studen_level==item.studen_level">
      <h2{{item.students_name}}></h2>
      <h3>{{item.course_id}} {{item.course_name}}</h3>
      <h3>{{studen_level}}</h3>
    </div>
```

Prueba esto ;)